# sorting a vector with class items in it

Tags: c++

lets say that i have a class that looks like this:

```
Class Items{
   private:
   float price;
   string name;
   float qunatity;
   public:
   getname(string nam){name=nam;}}
```

etc...

and i have a vector consisting of this class items, how would i then make it to sort the vector according to the users input like if the user wants to sort the items by name then it would sort by name etc.

EDIT::
ok so i have a class items and also have a class inventory:

```
Class Inventory{
      print();
      getdata();
      sort();
      static bool SORT_BY_NAME(const Item& i, const Item &j)}
```

then i have a function that Sang Geo wrote for the comparison

```
static bool Inventory::SORT_BY_NAME(const Item & i, const Item & j) {                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  return i.name.compare(j.name) < 0;
}
```

and then i also have a sort function that will use different bool sort functions

```
void Inventory::sorting(){
  int x;
  cout<<"How do you want to sort it: 1.name 2.ID 3.month";
  cin>>x;
  // vector<Item>::iterator it;                                                                                                   
  switch(x){
  case 1:
    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), Inventory::SORT_BY_NAME);
  }
```

but it says that Items::name is private

Comment: That's because your comparison function is within Inventory. You need to either move it to Item class, or modify Item::getname() to work properly. You implementation of Item::getname() does not make sense. Consider this: `string getname() { return name; }`. And in your comparison function (assuming you don't want it to be moved into Item class), replace `i.name` and `j.name` with `i.getname()` and `j.getname()` respectively.

Comment: @Song Gao it doesn't work as in both cases it gives me an error: cannot declare member function ‘static bool Inventory::SORT_BY_NAME(const Item&, const Item&)’ to have static linkage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To better illustrate how to use [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with your scenario, here's a complete example with three comparison functions defined for three fields in your class:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

class Item{
    public:
        float price;
        std::string name;
        float quantity;
        static bool SORT_BY_NAME(const Item & i, const Item & j) {
            return i.name.compare(j.name) < 0;
        }
        static bool SORT_BY_PRICE(const Item & i, const Item & j) {
            return i.price < j.price;
        }
        static bool SORT_BY_QUANTITY(const Item & i, const Item & j) {
            return i.quantity < j.quantity;
        }
        std::string ToString(){
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << name << ": $" << price << "; " << quantity;
            return ss.str();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::vector<Item> items;
    Item item1, item2, item3;

    item1.name = "Name1";
    item1.price = 2;
    item1.quantity = 3;

    item2.name = "Name2";
    item2.price = 3;
    item2.quantity = 1;

    item3.name = "Name3";
    item3.price = 1;
    item3.quantity = 2;

    items.push_back(item1);
    items.push_back(item2);
    items.push_back(item3);


    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), Item::SORT_BY_NAME);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"By name:"<<std::endl;
    for(std::vector<Item>::iterator i = items.begin(); i != items.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<i->ToString()<<std::endl;

    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), Item::SORT_BY_PRICE);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"By price:"<<std::endl;
    for(std::vector<Item>::iterator i = items.begin(); i != items.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<i->ToString()<<std::endl;

    std::sort(items.begin(), items.end(), Item::SORT_BY_QUANTITY);
    std::cout<<std::endl<<"By quantity:"<<std::endl;
    for(std::vector<Item>::iterator i = items.begin(); i != items.end(); ++i)
        std::cout<<i->ToString()<<std::endl;

}
```

Comment: thats pretty much what I was doing but I get error: no matching function for call to ‘Inventory::sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item, std::allocator<Item> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item, std::allocator<Item> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’

Comment: Hi @JackF Did you `#include <algorithm>`? Did you use `std::sort` or add `using namespace std;`? The `Inventory::sort` looks weird because `sort` should be within `std::` namespace. Also make sure your comparison function has proper type. It would help to look at your actual code...

Comment: I got the function almost working, but my name is private in the class and it cannot access it, i have a public accessor getname() but how would i use that in this function?

Comment: @JackF You may define the comparison function as a static class function of Item like the one above in my example, so it can access private field of the class. Alternatively, if you have a public accessor getname(), I believe you could use it anywhere even if the comparison function is not a class function. However, the comparison function needs to be either a public static function of the Item class, or anywhere outside the class that is accessible by the place, aka main function in the example above, you use `std::sort`.

Comment: @Sang Gao let me show you above what i have done and it says that it cannot access private name element

Comment: @JackF I didn't get it. Did you mean you'll update your post to show what you did?

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to write a comparison function for each field you want to sort on and depending on the user input select the right one.

See [sort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use a custom comparator object that either sorts according to `name`, `price` or `quantity`.

This is part of [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)'s functionality.

Answer (score 0):

`std::sort` algorithm has three parameters — first, last and *comparator*.

> Comparison function object that, taking two values of the same type
>   than those contained in the range, returns true if the first argument
>   goes before the second argument in the specific strict weak ordering
>   it defines, and false otherwise.

Comment: should i use the bool function?

Comment: @JackF, see the answer updated with description of comparator.

Comment: the problem is that i have like 15 class members so then i would have to have 15 bool functions ;/ is there like a faster way of doing that?

Comment: @JackF Well, there is only one bool function - that defines which element is before another.

Comment: @JackF if you want to decide at runtime which of the 15 data members to use for the sorting, then yes, you will need 15 functions.

Comment: @JackF Sort uses only one bool function - the one that you choose, so there is no runtime overhead when sorting, only when you have to choose your function.

Comment: ok so im trying to do the comparison and i get error: no matching function for call to ‘Inventory::sort(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item, std::allocator<Item> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Item*, std::vector<Item, std::allocator<Item> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
item.cpp:62: note: candidates are: void Inventory::sort()

Comment: You seem to try to use member sort, not `std::sort`. Show the code that gives you this error.